# Firefox small size file upload HTML5 file API

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

Firefox (v26) doesn't display the file's upload progress if that file's size is less than 70kb. There is no such problem on Chrome, IE 10-11, Opera 19.
I'm sending the image not as a binary data.

Has anybody encountered similar problem?

Comment: Why would you need or even care about upload progress for such a tiny file ?  It will upload instantly anyway.

Comment: @Ray Nicholus, you are right, but I want Firefox at least fill the progress bar. Other browsers fill the bar, but Firefox does nothing.

Comment: What does your code look like?  If you are relying on the upload.progress event, this is likely due to the way that Firefox adheres to the spec (by throttling/limiting the number of progress events).  Other browsers, such as Chrome, do not throttle.  I commented on this in an issue in the product I maintain (Fine Uploader) a while back: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/404#issuecomment-10124160

Comment: Yes, I rely on the upload progress event. It seems that Firefox doesn't fire that event, but when I check, the data is sent (the image is uploaded). When I set callbacks to see if the upload progress event or xhr.load event are fired in Firefox, they don't, at least, I don't receive any callbacks.
Thank's for the article. I'm currently reading it.
Is there a way to fix this behaviour or this is the way Firefox handles this particular job and there is no way to correct it?

Comment: I doubt Firefox is not firing the event at all.  Please show your code.

Comment: Thank you @Ray Nicholus. Your comments gave me a hint that helped solving this problem. The thing I was doing wrong is firing the onload event inside the xhr2.upload.onprogress event. like (function(xhr2){xhr2.upload.onprogress=function(e_){ xhr2.onload=function(e_){}}})(xhr2)

Comment: I created another anonymous function and put the onload event inside it which worked for me. Thank's again.

Comment: same issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/21369556/3477084 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/9550940/3477084 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14704572/3477084